# How to render a Microsoft Word document as .png images in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ms-word, rendering

is there any way (or a library) to convert a .doc/.docx document to a bunch of .png images, one for each page?
I know how to render PDFs as images, so maybe there is a way to convert a .doc/.docx as .png's?

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is opening the doc files in the webview and screenshot the following the page with this code snippet:-

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myWebView.bounds.size, myWebView.isOpaque, 0.0)
    myView.drawHierarchy(in: myWebView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let snapshotImageFromMyWebView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() // get your image from here
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

After that you want to scroll the webview to the next page, to take another screenshot by using:-

```
webview.scrollView.contentOffset
```

This will keep repeating until you reach the bottom of the page. Check this snippet right here:-

```
let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height - webView.frame.size.height)
```

I know the process is kind of lengthy and insane, but I don't think any library takes care of this process! So either first convert your doc to pdf and for that you can use Google Docs API and then from there you can take it forward.

I have heard about [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com) but it's paid, so I have not tried out their API.